# Is a menubar at the bottom of the screen not too much iOS6?

Tags: ios, menu

i need to design a mobile travel app and have quite a lot of functionalities to incorporate. I 'm thinking of hiding most of them in a top menu 'more' button. But i also like to leave the most used options directly at hand for the user. I was thinking of placing them in a fixed menubar at the bottom of the screen but to me it feels like an iOS6-thing, while i'm not really sure it is.
Is this iOS best practice?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

iOS users expect navigation buttons to exist at the bottom of the screen. Great examples of this include Photos, Music, App Store, etc. Note that if you have too many tabs in the `UITabBarController`, the last tab will be replaced with a "More" tab that allows the user to see all other tabs that aren't visible in the tab bar. Place your most often used or important tabs in the tab bar, and all others can go into More. You could also implement your own "More" tab to control its appearance.

[image]

I would not place such menu buttons below a navigation bar (like android). Additionally, users expect buttons in navigation bars will affect the content that's on screen, not provide any navigational utilities, so I wouldn't implement those there either.

I'll also note that Apple strongly recommends against using a hamburger icon that pulls out a sidebar to provide buttons to navigate.

Answer (score 0):

You mean the iOS 7 menu bar at the bottom of Safari, Mail, Phone, app store, iTunes... Yeah, it' still a thing. A bottom menu bar isn't necessarily a 'best practice'but it is a standard method of giving access to features and functionality within an application.

Comment: Yes, but that's the standard iOS menu bar, which personally i don't like that much. I was thinking of designing my own menu bar cause i'd like it to be more coherent with the rest of the app

Answer (score 0):

The bottom screen approach works very well for mobile applications due to the hands ergonomics. Often used functions would fit best in the bottom corner, to be reachable with the thumb at once.

There are some very good videos from Luke Wroblewski on youtube, especially this one which touches your challenge (see min 1:10): [Luke Wroblewski on navigation on touch](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tuIs8QYHktA&list=PLg-UKERBljNy2Yem3RJkYL1V70dpzkysC&index=25)

So don't think if this approach is too this or that. Just think of usage at first.